# How can I make a new page with customtkinter popup button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, customtkinter

I am trying to make a customtkinter application myself, but I had a problem somewhere, I searched and couldn't find it. When you press the button, a place you can choose opens, for example, there are 2 buttons called page 1 and Justin Hardy on page 1. If he presses the button and selects page 2, there is a button named Jessy and Charly on that page, how can I do this?

Or there will be fixed buttons above, for example page 1 and page 2. When you press them, the buttons at the bottom will change. The existing window should change, not the new window.How can ı do this?
Thank you in advance.

```
root.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root.sidebar_frame, text="Page Change", anchor="w")
        root.scaling_label.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        root.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(root.sidebar_frame, values=["PAGE1", "PAGE2", "PAGE3", "PAGE4", "PAGE5"],
                                                               command=??????)
        root.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=20, pady=(10,3))
```

I made such a button but I couldn't proceed. I didn't know what to write in the Commands section.